# Web API 2 with attribute routing getting same key error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

Why do I keep getting the error below about duplicate keys?  This worked fine before I tried attribute routing, but now it does not.  If I remove `{id:int}` it always hits the second method, never the first, even if no ID is supplied.

**EventsController**

```
[System.Web.Http.RoutePrefix("api/v1/events")]
    public partial class EventsController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
    {
        [System.Web.Http.Route("")]
        public virtual ApiEventsResponse Get([FromUri] ApiEventsRequest request)
        {
            .....

            return response;
        }

        [System.Web.Http.Route("{id:int}")]
        public virtual ApiEventResponse Get(int id, [FromUri] ApiEventRequest request)
        {
            .....

            return response;
        }
```

**Error when accessing /api/v1/events?id=12315**

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

An item with the same key has already been added.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.

Source Error: 


Line 407:            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
Line 408:
Line 409:            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
Line 410:            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
Line 411:

Source File: f:\My Webs\BasketballTournaments\MainBranch\Websites\Tournaments\Global.asax.cs    Line: 409 

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) +52
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) +11187358
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value) +10
   System.Web.Http.Routing.InlineRouteTemplateParser.ParseRouteTemplate(String routeTemplate, IDictionary`2 defaults, IDictionary`2 constraints, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver) +363
   System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRouteBuilder.BuildParsingRoute(String routeTemplate, Int32 order, IEnumerable`1 actions) +86
   System.Web.Http.HttpConfigurationExtensions.MapHttpAttributeRoutesInternal(HttpConfiguration configuration, HttpRouteBuilder routeBuilder) +232
   System.Web.Http.<>c__DisplayClass5.<MapHttpAttributeRoutes>b__4() +13
   System.Web.Http.Routing.RouteCollectionRoute.EnsureInitialized(Func`1 initializer) +70
   System.Web.Http.<>c__DisplayClass5.<MapHttpAttributeRoutes>b__3(HttpConfiguration config) +63
   System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized() +23
   System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Action`1 configurationCallback) +57
   Tournaments.MvcApplication.OnApplicationStarted() in f:\My Webs\BasketballTournaments\MainBranch\Websites\Tournaments\Global.asax.cs:409
   Ninject.Web.Common.NinjectHttpApplication.Application_Start() in c:\Projects\Ninject\Ninject.Web.Common\src\Ninject.Web.Common\NinjectHttpApplication.cs:82

[HttpException (0x80004005): An item with the same key has already been added.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9903113
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): An item with the same key has already been added.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9882460
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
namespace Tournaments.App_Start
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Filters.Add(new ExceptionHandlingAttribute());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Based the controller you provided above, I tried to repro it but I wasn't able to...could you share the skeletal structure of the rest of the actions in this controller? From the error message, it appears that same key is being added into a dictionary...could you share the full stack trace?

Comment: Full stack trace added.

Comment: Thanks Mike..Could you share how your WebApiConfig.cs looks like...from the error looks like you are trying to add a new inline constraint named `int` into the dictionary..is it?

Comment: Added the webapiconfig.cs

Comment: hmm, very strange..i am just unable to reproduce your issue based on the information above...the stack trace clearly indicates that the exception is happening when duplicate key is being added to the dictionary...are you seeing your application work if you comment out the route having `{id:int}`?...my only guess is that `MapHttpAttributeRoutes` might be getting called multiple times...i see Ninject from stack trace, wondering if its doing something funky by calling the configuration multiple times...by the way, the inline constraints only applies to non-query string route data...

Comment: Yea I took off the {int:int} and I can only reach the correct one if I add the Order property to the attribute.  It just doesnt pick it up like it used to with the default routing setup.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41060/discussion-between-kiran-challa-and-mike-flynn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer but I just went back to my original.  I think the original problem is I have two apis, and since you cant namespace web api routes yet there were duplicate key issues because the `EventsController` was listed twice but under different namespaces.  That was the duplicate key issue, but for the `{id:int}` never working for a query string you got me.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DefaultApi",
            "api/v{version}/{controller}/{id}", 
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, version = 1 }
        );

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DefaultApiAction",
            "api/v{version}/{controller}/{action}"
        );
```